# having two or more worker queues in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

So I have 2 main worker processes one is supposed to fetch content of a URL and the other 
will insert each of the anchor links into a postgre table. Now I am running 
12 instances of the first process all of which taking their URL from a single URL queue, and then placing the anchors in a second queue but how do I have an other set of threads trying to push the Anchors into the table? when I start the threads the find their queue empty and they die, if I disable that feature they wont die when the work is done, how do I manage this, and by the way is it better to use process instead of thread because of presumably intensive IO interaction involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need two queues the `URLFetchers` will pop URLs from one queue and push into a second one, then the `AnchorInserters` should pop from this second queue to process the data. This organisation should give you a good sync mechanism for your problem.

**Edit: to avoid worker exiting**

You need to block till one element is available.

```
while True:
   element = queue.get(block=True, timeout=None)
   #do worker's task
```

From python's `queue.get` [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get) ...

> If optional args block is true and
>   timeout is None (the default), block
>   if necessary until an item is
>   available.

Comment: by default my worker thread does a sys.exit(0) if the queue is empty, and at the beginning the second queue is empty, when I do disable that, it does infinite wait even after work is done.

Comment: @max see new edition of the question, I think I get what's your issue.